# Plotting word frequency: top 10

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot the most frequent words (10) using a bar chart.
I already computed their frequency as follows

```
my_list.plot = (df['Food'].value_counts())
```

Output

```
olives      16
salt        12
tomato      10
oil         10
water        7
             ..
avocado      1
mango        1
watermelon   1
banana       1
```

And I plotted the list above as follows:

```
my_list.plot(kind='bar',stacked=False, figsize=(16,8))
plt.show()
```

This generates a bar chart with all the frequencies (approx. 150). 
Since it is difficult to read the figure, I would like to ask how I can plot only the top 10.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the top `10` with `head`:

```
my_list.plot = (df['Food'].value_counts())

my_list.head(10).plot(kind='bar',stacked=False, figsize=(16,8))
```